# What should I use to draw Quads on openGl 3.1 or above?

Tags: opengl

I've started to learn OpenGL few days ago and I just realised that Quad and Polygons are now deprecated on OpenGL 3.1 or above. The information I found [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive) after having an error on a beginner tutorial which I just wanted to make a change between a triangle to a square. Anyway, instead of use `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE, 0, 3);` I changed the code to `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);` and I got what I wanted. But my questions are:

1 - If triangle fan isnt the best option now a days to draw a simple square what should I use to do it on openGL 3.1 or above?

2 - Why exactly Polygons and Quads became deprecated after a while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - If triangle fan isnt the best option now a days to draw a simple square what should I use to do it on openGL 3.1 or above?

Downside of the triangle-fan approach is you can't render them in batches without getting creative with degenerate triangles or dropping back to indexed rednering and primitive restart.

`GL_TRIANGLES` lets you keep `glDrawArrays()` and do large batches at the expense of 2 extra vertices per quad.

> 2 - Why exactly Polygons and Quads became deprecated after a while?

Quads are decomposed into triangles before rasterization.  Khronos just cut out the middleman.

Comment: so, let me see if I really got the idea, instead of triangle fan should I draw two simple triangles?

Comment: If you want to draw a batch of quads using `glDrawArrays()`, yes.

Comment: And what other option could you suggest for me?

Comment: "getting creative with degenerate triangles or dropping back to indexed rednering and primitive restart"